# hierarchy table to open all connections level into rows - snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have an hierarchy table that includes connections between entities.
for example:

| entity_id | entity_type | resource_id | resource_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 2 | Y |
| 2 | Y | 3 | Y |
| 3 | Y | 4 | Z |

what i would like to get in the end:

| entity_id | entity_type | resource_id | resource_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 2 | Y |
| 2 | Y | 3 | Y |
| 3 | Y | 4 | Z |
| 1 | X | 3 | Y |
| 1 | Y | 4 | Z |
| 2 | Y | 4 | Z |

I tried to join to itself with multi joins ( I know i have a max of 5 levels deep).
but it only bring the final connections ( 1-4 for example) and not the between connections  ( 2-4, 1-3)

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: Given the problem description you have provided, you have statically join multiple joins, to get the intermediate steps you need to do a recursive building. the doc's might help you, given they have this exact problem as the examples: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-hierarchical

Answer (score 0):

You have to use recursive cte to get the desire result. find below the sql snippet

```
with cte as(
    select entity_id,entity_type,resource_id,resource_type from q1
    union all
    select cte.entity_id,cte.entity_type,q1.resource_id,q1.resource_type 
    from cte
    inner join q1 
    on cte.resource_id=q1.entity_id
)
select * from cte;
```